# space issue in CURL with Runtime

Tags: java, jsp, curl

I have a CURL command which need to be run with the `Runtime` method in a JSP file

```
int cnt=10;    
String strCount="count"+cnt+"";
String msg= "{'text':'"+strCount+"'}";
String cmd = "curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data "+ msg +" https://hooks.slack.com/services/#####/###/###";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Which works fine, but when I change `strCount` to:

```
String strCount="Count is "+cnt+"";
```

It doesn't work anymore. It's clear that the space between `Count is` is not working anymore.

Comment: You must use the `exec(String[])` method and pass each argument individually.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik am newbie for java things, can you make more sense on this please ?

Comment: `rt.exec("curl", "-X", "POST", "-H", ...)`

Comment: Just a heads up, your curl method may work, but honestly if this is getting data that's possibly from any user or message that's not controlled by you, i'd think twice, it's not too hard to exploit a program passing raw user input into an exec call.

Comment: Your problem also lies in the fact that that program has no way of knowing if that space in your text is either a space in your text, or a separate argument to use, you could try quoting the argument, but i think Marko's answer above is far better than quoting it.

Comment: now am getting error like `The method exec(String, String[], File) in the type Runtime is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to this.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"curl","-X", "POST","-H","'Content-type: application/json'","--data", msg, "https://hooks.slack.com/services/#####/###/###"});
```

as per the [Runtime#exec() docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])), you can pass individual arguments with spaces in them if you make them an array, as seen above.

Comment: Thanks, but no luck , getting same result

Comment: Can you elaborate? What exactly are you getting as a result?

Comment: my scenario is exactly what explained in my question, when i add space in my json arguement it doesn't work, if there is no space then my call is working

Comment: I assume when you say it doesn't work, you mean it doesn't post to slack.  Are there any errors returned by the server?

Comment: `curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data "{'text':'Count is'}" https://hooks.slack.com/services/###/####/###` , When i try this from server its working fine getting message from slack , when i run the same with Runtime, it doesn't return any error, but am not getting message from slack

Comment: Get the output and see what curl is saying, maybe it'll give you a helpful error message or something :)