# Send a POST request in scala using cURL command to slack

Tags: scala, curl, slack

I am trying to send a message to slack from `Scala` using `CURL` command. It gives error invalid payload

```
val slackurl = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/<something here>  
  val cmd = Seq(
    "curl",
    "-d",
    "testdata",
    "-H",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "-X",
    "POST",
    slackurl
  )
  cmd.!
```

i am getting the error "invalid_payload"

or

```
 val cmd = Seq(
    "curl",
    "-d",
    s"@$testData",
    "-H",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "-X",
    "POST",
    slackurl
  )
```

when I am trying to send some data, the error is : "`cant read from the file`"

Comment: I did not used with sequence collection. But there are other ways to do; Such as writing as all string at a time  like s"curl -d @$testData -H Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded -X POST $slackurl".!

Comment: And make sure that you have defined curl executable  path in ENV. if not , you can use Process("curl  blah blah", new File("YOURPATH"), "PATH" -> "executable path")

Comment: Why?Why using an external process? While there are many good HTTP libs?

Comment: i used the following:  `Runtime.getRuntime.exec(
    Array[String](
      "curl",
      "-X",
      "POST",
      "-H",
      "Content-type: application/json",
      "--data",
      actData,
      slackurl
    )
  )`  
 Its working for me now. 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262909/space-issue-in-curl-with-runtime]

Comment: Awesome. Post your solution as answer please so we can close this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i used the following: Runtime.getRuntime.exec( Array[String]( "curl", "-X", "POST", "-H", "Content-type: application/json", "--data", actData, slackurl ) ) Its working for me now. [[space issue in CURL with Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262909/space-issue-in-curl-with-runtime])
But when i send the a json to slack, message was displayed as "Array".